# Trying to implement a red-black tree in C

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I need help implementing a red-black tree It seems to keep seg faulting on my malloc calls. I am not sure how to fix it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. The functions appear to be working the only issues i have are with allocating memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    char color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

Node **Root = NULL;

// A utility function to create a new BST node
Node *newNode(int data) {
    Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->color = 'R';
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    return temp;
}

void rotateLeft(Node **Root, Node *New) {
    Node *lPtr = New->right;
    New->right = lPtr->left;

    if (lPtr->left != NULL)
        lPtr->left->parent = New;
    lPtr->parent = New->parent;
    if (New->parent == NULL)
        *Root = lPtr;
    else if (New->data == New->parent->left->data)
        New->parent->left = lPtr;
    else
        New->parent->right = lPtr;
    lPtr->left = New;
    New->parent = lPtr;
}

void rotateRight (Node**Root, Node *New) {
    Node *rPtr = New->left;
    New->left = rPtr->right;

    if (rPtr->right != NULL)
        rPtr->right->parent = New;
    rPtr->parent = New->parent;
    if (New->parent == NULL)
        *Root = rPtr;
    else if (New->data == New->parent->left->data)
        New->parent->left = rPtr;
    else
        New->parent->right = rPtr;
    rPtr->right = New;
    New->parent = rPtr;
}

void redBlackInsertFixup(Node **Root, Node *New) {
    Node* temp;
    while (New->parent->color == 'R') {
        if (New->parent->data == New->parent->parent->data) { 
            temp = New->parent->parent->right;
            if (temp->color == 'R') {
                New->parent->color = 'B';
                temp->color = 'B';
                New->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                New = New->parent->parent;
            } else
            if (New->data == New->parent->right->data) {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateLeft(Root,New);
            }
            New->parent->color = 'B';
            New->parent->parent->color = 'R';
            rotateRight(Root, New->parent->parent);
        } else {
            temp = New->parent->parent->left;
            if (temp->color == 'R') {
                New->parent->color = 'B';
                New->color = 'B';
                New->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                New = New->parent->parent;
            } else
            if (New->data == New->parent->left->data) {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateRight(Root, New);
            }
            New->parent->color = 'B';
            New->parent->parent->color = 'R';
            rotateLeft(Root, New->parent->parent);
        }
    }
    Root[0]->color = 'B';
}

void redBlackInsert(Node **Root, int data) {  
    Node *New = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    New->data = data;
    New->left = NULL;
    New->right = NULL;
    New->color = 'R';
    Node *Yp = NULL;
    Node *Xp = *Root;
    if (*Root != NULL) {
        New->color = 'B';
        *Root = New;
        return;
    }
    while (Xp != NULL) {
        Yp = Xp;
        if (data < Xp->data)
            Xp = Xp->left;
        Xp = Xp->right;
    }
    New->parent = Yp;
    if (Yp == NULL) {
        *Root = New;
        if (data < Yp->data)
            Yp->left = New;
        else
            Yp->right = New;
    }
    New->left = NULL;
    New->right = NULL;
    New->color = 'R';
    redBlackInsertFixup(Root, New);
}

void redBlackTreePrint(Node *Root) {
    Node* temp = Root;
    if (temp != NULL) {
        redBlackTreePrint(temp->left);
        printf(" %d - %c,", temp->data, temp->color == 'B' ? 'B' : 'R');
        redBlackTreePrint(temp->right);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    redBlackInsert(Root, 7);
    redBlackInsert(Root, 9);
    redBlackTreePrint(*Root);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The best advice you'll get is to use a debugger. At the very minimum it will tell you immediately exactly which line of code is triggering the sef fault.

Comment: It dies on line 120: when it dereferences *Root when Root is Null

Answer (score 2):

Compile it with -g flags, and run with gdb, and you will find that it traps on line 120 at redBlackInsert because *Root is NULL.

```
scott > gcc -O0 -g redblack.c -o redblack
scott > redblack
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
scott > gdb redblack
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/scott/stackOverflow/redblack/redblack 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040098c in redBlackInsert (Root=0x0, data=7) at redblack.c:120
120     Node* Xp = *Root;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040098c in redBlackInsert (Root=0x0, data=7) at redblack.c:120
#1  0x0000000000400af5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at redblack.c:164
(gdb)
```

I modified the global Root to be "Node *Root" rather than "**Root" since this is more intuitive. Its three uses in main() had to be modified to match:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
     redBlackInsert(&Root, 7);
     redBlackInsert(&Root, 9);
     redBlackTreePrint(Root);
     return 0;
 }
```

On 138, you check if yp==NULL, then you dereference it which causes a segmentation fault on 139:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/scott/stackOverflow/redblack/redblack 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a0f in redBlackInsert (Root=0x601050 <Root>, data=7) at redblack.c:139
139         if(data < Yp->data)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400a0f in redBlackInsert (Root=0x601050 <Root>, data=7) at redblack.c:139
#1  0x0000000000400af2 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at redblack.c:165
(gdb)
```

Sorry, that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution based on "Introduction to Algorithms", chapter 13 "Red-Black Trees", by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define RED   'R'
#define BLACK 'B'


typedef struct Node{
    int          key;
    char         color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

// Based on CLRS algorithm, use T_Nil as a sentinel to simplify code
struct Node  T_Nil_Node;
       Node* T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;

Node* Root = NULL;

// A utility function to create a new BST node
Node* newNode(int key)
{
    Node *temp   = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->key    = key;
    temp->color  = RED;
    temp->left   = NULL;
    temp->right  = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    return temp;
}
void rotateLeft( Node** T, Node* x)
{
    Node *y  = x->right;    // set y
    x->right = y->left;     // turn y's left subtree into x's right subtree{
    if (y->left != T_Nil)
        y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;  // link x's parent to y
    if (x->parent == T_Nil)
       *T = y;
    else if (x == x->parent->left)
       x->parent->left = y;
    else
       x->parent->right = y;
    y->left   = x;            // put x on y's left
    x->parent = y;
}

void rotateRight(Node** T, Node* y)
{
    Node *x  = y->left;     // set x
    y->left  = x->right;    // turn x's right subtree into y's left subtree{
    if (x->right != T_Nil)
        x->right->parent = y;
    x->parent = y->parent;  // link y's parent to x
    if (y->parent == T_Nil)
       *T = x;
    else if (y == y->parent->right)
       y->parent->right = x;
    else
       y->parent->left  = x;
    x->right  = y;         // put y on x's right
    y->parent = x;
}
void redBlackInsertFixup(Node** Root, Node* New)
{
Node* temp;
    while(New->parent->color == RED)
    {
        if(New->parent->key == New->parent->parent->key)
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->right;
            if(temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                temp->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else if(New->key == New->parent->right->key)
            {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateLeft(Root,New);
            }
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            rotateRight(Root,New->parent->parent);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->left;
            if(temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else if(New->key == New->parent->left->key)
            {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateRight(Root,New);
            }
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            rotateLeft(Root, New->parent->parent);
        }
    }
    Root[0]->color = BLACK;
}
void redBlackInsert(Node** T, int key)
{
    Node* z =  newNode(key);
    Node* y =  T_Nil;
    Node* x = *T;

    // Find where to Insert new node Z into the binary search tree
    while (x != T_Nil) {
       y = x;
       if (z->key < x->key)
          x = x->left;
       else
          x = x->right;
    }

    z->parent = y;
    if (y == T_Nil)
       *T = z;
    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left  = z;
    else
        y->right = z;

    // Init z as a red leaf
    z->left  = T_Nil;
    z->right = T_Nil;
    z->color = RED;

    // Ensure the Red-Black property is maintained
    redBlackInsertFixup(T,z);
}

#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int height(Node* Root)
{
 int h = 0;

 if (Root != NULL) {
    if (Root == T_Nil)
       h = 1;
    else
      {
       int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
       int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
       h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
      }
   }

 return h;
}


int blackHeight(Node* Root)
{
 int height = 0;

 while (Root) {
    if ((Root == T_Nil) || (Root->color == BLACK))
       height++;
    Root = Root->left;
 }
 return height;
}

void PrintHelper(Node* Root)
{
    Node* temp = Root;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        PrintHelper(temp->left);
        printf(" %d%c(h=%d,bh=%d) ", temp->key, (temp->color == BLACK ? BLACK : RED), height(temp), blackHeight(temp));
        PrintHelper(temp->right);
    }
}
void redBlackTreePrint(Node* Root)
{
    printf("Tree Height=%d, Black-Height=%d\n", height(Root), blackHeight(Root));
    PrintHelper(Root);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node* Root = T_Nil;

    redBlackInsert(&Root, 7);
    redBlackInsert(&Root, 9);
    redBlackTreePrint(Root);
}
```

Your bug appeared to be in redBlackInsert(). When I rewrote it, the segmentation faults disappeared. One thing to consider when fixing your code: use a sentinal node in your tree. This will simplify the logic around handling edge cases where you derefence null pointers. The CRLS textbook describes how this greatly simplifies Red-Black coding. Your bug may be related to mishandling edge cases.

Here is a sample run using your main():

```
scott > gcc -O0 -g redblack.c -o redblack
scott > redblack
Tree Height=3, Black-Height=2
 0R(h=1,bh=1)  7B(h=3,bh=2)  0R(h=1,bh=1)  9R(h=2,bh=1)  0R(h=1,bh=1)
```

I modified readBlackTreePrint to display each node's height in the tree, and the each node's black-height (defined as the number of black nodes in its simple path to a leaf).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The global variable `Root` is a pointer to a pointer initialized to `NULL`: `Node **Root = NULL;`.  This is not what `redBlackInsert()` expects: you should pass the address of the root node, which does not need to be a global variable:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      Node *Root = NULL;
      redBlackInsert(&Root, 7);
      redBlackInsert(&Root, 9);
      redBlackTreePrint(Root);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- You forget to initialize the `parent` member of the new node in `redBlackInsert()`.  You should just use `newNode()`:

  ```
  Node *New = newNode(data);
  ```
- The test for an empty tree in `redBlackInsert()` is incorrect:  `if (*Root != NULL)` should be changed to:

  ```
  if (*Root == NULL) {
      New->color = 'B';
      *Root = New;
      return;
  }
  ```

With these modifications, the program runs and outputs this:

```
 7 - B,
```

which is incorrect but gives you a head start for where to look.

Answer (score 1):

PanagiotisP is right, there are mistakes in ScottK's and cesign's code.
The corrected code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define RED   'R'
#define BLACK 'B'


typedef struct Node{
    int          key;
    char         color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

// Based on CLRS algorithm, use T_Nil as a sentinel to simplify code
struct Node  T_Nil_Node;
       Node* T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;

Node* Root = NULL;

// A utility function to create a new BST node
Node* newNode(int key)
{
    Node *temp   = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->key    = key;
    temp->color  = RED;
    temp->left   = NULL;
    temp->right  = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    return temp;
}
void rotateLeft( Node** T, Node* x)
{
    Node *y  = x->right;    // set y
    x->right = y->left;     // turn y's left subtree into x's right subtree{
    if (y->left != T_Nil)
        y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;  // link x's parent to y
    if (x->parent == T_Nil)
       *T = y;
    else if (x == x->parent->left)
       x->parent->left = y;
    else
       x->parent->right = y;
    y->left   = x;            // put x on y's left
    x->parent = y;
}

void rotateRight(Node** T, Node* y)
{
    Node *x  = y->left;     // set x
    y->left  = x->right;    // turn x's right subtree into y's left subtree{
    if (x->right != T_Nil)
        x->right->parent = y;
    x->parent = y->parent;  // link y's parent to x
    if (y->parent == T_Nil)
       *T = x;
    else if (y == y->parent->right)
       y->parent->right = x;
    else
       y->parent->left  = x;
    x->right  = y;         // put y on x's right
    y->parent = x;
}
void redBlackInsertFixup(Node** Root, Node* New)
{
    Node* temp;
    while(New->parent->color == RED)
    {
        if(New->parent->key == New->parent->parent->key)
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->right;
            if(temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                temp->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else 
            { 
                if(New->key == New->parent->right->key)
                {
                    New = New->parent;
                    rotateLeft(Root,New);
                }
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                rotateRight(Root,New->parent->parent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->left;
            if(temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                temp->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else 
            { 
                if(New->key == New->parent->left->key)
                {
                    New = New->parent;
                    rotateRight(Root,New);
                }
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                rotateLeft(Root, New->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    Root[0]->color = BLACK;
}
void redBlackInsert(Node** T, int key)
{
    Node* z =  newNode(key);
    Node* y =  T_Nil;
    Node* x = *T;

    // Find where to Insert new node Z into the binary search tree
    while (x != T_Nil) {
       y = x;
       if (z->key < x->key)
          x = x->left;
       else
          x = x->right;
    }

    z->parent = y;
    if (y == T_Nil)
       *T = z;
    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left  = z;
    else
        y->right = z;

    // Init z as a red leaf
    z->left  = T_Nil;
    z->right = T_Nil;
    z->color = RED;

    // Ensure the Red-Black property is maintained
    redBlackInsertFixup(T,z);
}

#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int height(Node* Root)
{
 int h = 0;

 if (Root != NULL) {
    if (Root == T_Nil)
       h = 1;
    else
      {
       int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
       int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
       h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
      }
   }

 return h;
}


int blackHeight(Node* Root)
{
 int height = 0;

 while (Root) {
    if ((Root == T_Nil) || (Root->color == BLACK))
       height++;
    Root = Root->left;
 }
 return height;
}

void PrintHelper(Node* Root)
{
    Node* temp = Root;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        PrintHelper(temp->left);
        printf(" %d%c(h=%d,bh=%d) ", temp->key, (temp->color == BLACK ? BLACK : RED), height(temp), blackHeight(temp));
        PrintHelper(temp->right);
    }
}
void redBlackTreePrint(Node* Root)
{
    printf("Tree Height=%d, Black-Height=%d\n", height(Root), blackHeight(Root));
    PrintHelper(Root);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node* Root = T_Nil;

    redBlackInsert(&Root, 7);
    redBlackInsert(&Root, 6);
    redBlackInsert(&Root, 9);
    redBlackInsert(&Root, 8);
    redBlackTreePrint(Root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of ScottK has little problem, I changed as blow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define RED   'R'
#define BLACK 'B'


typedef struct Node {
    int          key;
    char         color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

// Based on CLRS algorithm, use T_Nil as a sentinel to simplify code
struct Node  T_Nil_Node;
Node* T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;

Node* Root = NULL;

// A utility function to create a new BST node
Node* newNode(int key)
{
    Node *temp   = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->key    = key;
    temp->color  = RED;
    temp->left   = NULL;
    temp->right  = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    return temp;
}

void rotateLeft( Node** T, Node* x)
{
    Node *y  = x->right;    // set y
    x->right = y->left;     // turn y's left subtree into x's right subtree{
    if (y->left != T_Nil)
        y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;  // link x's parent to y
    if (x->parent == T_Nil)
        *T = y;
    else if (x == x->parent->left)
        x->parent->left = y;
    else
        x->parent->right = y;
    y->left   = x;            // put x on y's left
    x->parent = y;
}

void rotateRight(Node** T, Node* y)
{
    Node *x  = y->left;     // set x
    y->left  = x->right;    // turn x's right subtree into y's left subtree{
    if (x->right != T_Nil)
        x->right->parent = y;
    x->parent = y->parent;  // link y's parent to x
    if (y->parent == T_Nil)
        *T = x;
    else if (y == y->parent->right)
        y->parent->right = x;
    else
        y->parent->left  = x;
    x->right  = y;         // put y on x's right
    y->parent = x;
}

void redBlackInsertFixup(Node** Root, Node* New)
{
    Node* temp;
    while (New->parent->color == RED)
    {
        if (New->parent == New->parent->parent->left)
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->right;
            if (temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                temp->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else {
                if (New == New->parent->right)
                {
                    New = New->parent;
                    rotateLeft(Root, New);
                }
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                rotateRight(Root, New->parent->parent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = New->parent->parent->left;
            if (temp->color == RED)
            {
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                New = New->parent->parent;
            }
            else {
                if (New == New->parent->left)
                {
                    New = New->parent;
                    rotateRight(Root, New);
                }
                New->parent->color = BLACK;
                New->parent->parent->color = RED;
                rotateLeft(Root, New->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    Root[0]->color = BLACK;
}
void redBlackInsert(Node** T, int key)
{
    Node* z =  newNode(key);
    Node* y =  T_Nil;
    Node* x = *T;

    // Find where to Insert new node Z into the binary search tree
    while (x != T_Nil) {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }

    z->parent = y;
    if (y == T_Nil)
        *T = z;
    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left  = z;
    else
        y->right = z;

    // Init z as a red leaf
    z->left  = T_Nil;
    z->right = T_Nil;
    z->color = RED;

    // Ensure the Red-Black property is maintained
    redBlackInsertFixup(T, z);
}

#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int height(Node* Root)
{
    int h = 0;

    if (Root != NULL) {
        if (Root == T_Nil)
            h = 1;
        else
        {
            int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
            int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
            h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
        }
    }

    return h;
}

//中序遍历
void printTree(Node* root)
{
    if (root->left != T_Nil)
        printTree(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->key);
    if (root->right != T_Nil)
        printTree(root->right);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node* Root = T_Nil;
    int list[10] = {1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d ", list[i]);
        redBlackInsert(&Root, list[i]);
    }
    printTree(Root);
}
```

Comment: What was the little problem? Would like to correct my post if I made a mistake. Thanks

Comment: @ScottK Your mistake is in the first if statement for redBlackInsertFixup. You leave our the `->left` in the expression `New->parent == New->parent->parent->left`

Comment: @scottK Also, the structure of the the if, else if inside of your function `redBlackInsertFixup` is slightly off. It should have an if and an else, and inside the else it should have an if, and the code following it. It changes the logic just slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a mistake in ScottK's and cesign's code.

In the **redBlackInsertFixup** function inside the following if statement:

**Wrong Code**

```
if (temp->color == RED)
{
    New->parent->color = BLACK;
    New->color = BLACK;
    New->parent->parent->color = RED;
    New = New->parent->parent;
}
```

**Corrected Code**

```
if (temp->color == RED)
{
    New->parent->color = BLACK;
    temp->color = BLACK;
    New->parent->parent->color = RED;
    New = New->parent->parent;
}
```

as you can see the following line has changed:

```
temp->color = BLACK; // Error: New->color = BLACK;
```

The error with this line can be seen when we insert the elements {7, 6, 9, 8} in this order. The resulting tree the previous code was producing:

```
            7(B)
       ______|______
      |             |
     6(R)          9(B)
   ___|___       ___|___
  |       |     |       |
T_NIL  T_NIL   8(B)   T_NIL
```

as you can see the property of the red-black tree, that any path from one node must have the same number of black nodes, is not maintained as there are two more black (B) nodes on the right path from the root than on the left path.

With the new code the resulting tree is:

```
            7(B)
       ______|______
      |             |
     6(B)          9(B)
   ___|___       ___|___
  |       |     |       |
T_NIL  T_NIL   8(R)   T_NIL
```

Which maintains all the red-black tree properties.

**Note:**
I can't comment on ScottK's or cesign's answer because commenting on StackOverflow requires reputation >= 50.